# How safe is DiskWarrior?

Tags: data-recovery, drobo, filesystem-corruption

My Drobo failed, and on googling i find that i should use diskwarrior.  How safe is disk warrior, can it do more unrecoverable damage?

I think the mbr just screwed up

Comment: The mbr screwed up? Are the discs fine? Perhaps you just need to replace the drobo.

Comment: DiskWarrior is incredible. It is a mighty, magical wand of wonder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raid data recovery is hard enough, but Drobo uses a custom raid-5-like implementation (it's not X-RAID) which I would assume no off-the-shelf software will handle.

I would recommend contacting Drobo support directly, depending on exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Drobo support suggested Disc Warrior when my Drobo couldn't be recognized as a disc. It worked perfectly and the Drobo has been up for a year since. I've had other success with DW as well.